# Reverse URL in template

Tags: python, tornado

In a template, how can I map a name back into a URL, similar to Django's `{% url %}` tag?

I read that `reverse_url` was supposed to work, but this gave an error:

```html
<li> <a href="{% reverse_url('login') %}">Login</a> </li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `{{ reverse_url('login') }}`. That is, a template expression rather than directive. The [syntax reference is here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html#syntax-reference) (it's brief).